# Golang вопрос по парсингу yaml (структура)

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Есть yaml c инвентори для ansible вида

```
all:
  children:
    subsystem:
      children:
        cb:
          hosts:
            cb01:
              ansible_host: cb01.domen.ru
            cb02:
              ansible_host: cb02.domen.ru
            cb03:
              ansible_host: cb03.domen.ru
```

Как для такого инвентори сделать универсальную структуру, чтобы при добавлении/удалении хоста не переписывать код программы?
Сейчас структура выглядит так

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    All struct {
        Children struct {
            Subsystem struct {
                Children struct {
                    Cb struct {
                        Hosts struct {
                            Cb01 struct {
                                AnsibleHost string `json:"ansible_host"`
                            } `json:"cb01"`
                            Cb02 struct {
                                AnsibleHost string `json:"ansible_host"`
                            } `json:"cb02"`
                            Cb03 struct {
                                AnsibleHost string `json:"ansible_host"`
                            } `json:"cb03"`
                        } `json:"hosts"`
                    } `json:"cb"`
                } `json:"children"`
            } `json:"subsystem"`
        } `json:"children"`
    } `json:"all"`
}
```

Но она будет не валидна, если к примеру добавить новый хост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно структуру Host представить в виде map новой структуры, к примеру Cb. Вот только map не гарантирует точную последовательность как в yaml файле.

Мой пример:

```
type Cb struct {
    AnsibleHost string `yaml:"ansible_host"`
}

type Hosts map[string]Cb

type AutoGenerated struct {
    All struct {
        Children struct {
            Subsystem struct {
                Children struct {
                    Cb struct {
                        Hosts Hosts `yaml:"hosts"`
                    } `yaml:"cb"`
                } `yaml:"children"`
            } `yaml:"subsystem"`
        } `yaml:"children"`
    } `yaml:"all"`
}
...
m := AutoGenerated{}
yaml.Unmarshal(data, &m)
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", m.All.Children.Subsystem.Children.Cb.Hosts))
```

На выходе получатся такие данные:

```
map[cb02:{AnsibleHost:cb02.domen.ru} cb03:{AnsibleHost:cb03.domen.ru} cb04:{AnsibleHost:cb04.domen.ru} cb01:{AnsibleHost:cb01.domen.ru}]
```

Полный пример https://play.golang.com/p/7hZdNdmqh5I

Comment: Супер! То что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте

```
Children struct {
    Cb struct {
        Hosts []string `json:"hosts"`
    } `json:"cb"`
} `json:"children"`
```

И поменяйте конфиг на такой формат

```
children:
  cb:
    hosts:
      - "cb01.domen.ru"
      - "cb02.domen.ru"
      - "cb03.domen.ru"
```

Comment: Инвентори менять нельзя